# SSL connection with Qt fails

Tags: qt, ssl

I use the following code to connect to a HTTPS page:

```
QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://sso.post.ch/organizer/?login"));

QList<QSslCertificate> cas;
cas.append(QSslCertificate::fromPath("/foo/VerisignCA_G3.crt"));
cas.append(QSslCertificate::fromPath("/foo/VerisignCA_G5.crt"));

QSslConfiguration sslConf;
sslConf.setCaCertificates(cas);
request.setSslConfiguration(sslConf);

QNetworkReply *reply = nam.get(request);
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(httpFinished()));
connect(&nam, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, QList<QSslError>)),
        this, SLOT(sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, QList<QSslError>)));
```

However, this request fails with the following error message (I ommit the code that prints it):

```
SSL errors occured while connecting to https://sso.post.ch/organizer/?login:

The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found
  s:[O=VeriSign, Inc.,CN=VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3,L=,OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,S=64:1b:e8:20:ce:02:08:13:f3:2d:4d:2d:95:d6:7e:67]
  i:[O=VeriSign, Inc.,CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5,L=,OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only,CN=VeriSign Trust Network] 
The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose
  s:[O=VeriSign, Inc.,CN=VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3,L=,OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,S=64:1b:e8:20:ce:02:08:13:f3:2d:4d:2d:95:d6:7e:67]
  i:[O=VeriSign, Inc.,CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5,L=,OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only,CN=VeriSign Trust Network] 

Installed CAs: 
0: s:[O=VeriSign, Inc.,CN=VeriSign Class 3 International Server CA - G3,L=,OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,S=64:1b:e8:20:ce:02:08:13:f3:2d:4d:2d:95:d6:7e:67]
   i:[O=VeriSign, Inc.,CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5,L=,OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only,CN=VeriSign Trust Network]
1: s:[O=VeriSign, Inc.,CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5,L=,OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,S=18:da:d1:9e:26:7d:e8:bb:4a:21:58:cd:cc:6b:3b:4a]
   i:[O=VeriSign, Inc.,CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5,L=,OU=(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only,CN=VeriSign Trust Network]
```

The strange thing is, that this chain validates with openssl from the command line:

```
openssl s_client -CAfile VerisignCA_G5.crt -connect sso.post.ch:443
  [...]
  Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

VerisignCA_G5.crt can be found [here](http://www.verisign.com/repository/roots/root-certificates/PCA-3G5.pem) and Verisign CA_G3.crt (MIIGKT...5mo) is from the chain that the server provides (and is IMHO not required to be added to the list of CAs).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried to print out the ssl error or that is what we see above?

Comment: That's what we see above. It is printed out in the sslErrors slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some certificates had the "X509v3 Authority Key Identifier" extension set. This requires an exact version of that issuer certificate and not only one with the same subject.